# get list of latitude and longitude using google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to get list of latitude and longitude using google map

i have this kind of flow

1. enter zip code
2. enter distance in miles such as (5,10,20,30,40,50)

Output :-

this will be generate a list of latitude and longitude with in given distance and zip code.

is it possible throw google map?

please kindly reply if anybody have solution of this.

Comment: The details here are very vague. What are you trying to plot or find? 
Are these points of latitude and longitude places of interest? Businesses? 
Random points on a map? 
Or the borders of the zip code you've entered?

Answer (score 0):

Google maps has a nice little page you can access to get geo coordinates:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=New%20York&output=csv&key=YOURGOOGLEAPIKEY
```

You'll need a google API key. And then just replace "New%20York" with your location. And it will output this:

```
200,4,40.7143528,-74.0059731
```

the 3rd and 4th item are the latitude and longitude

Comment: No Coomie.i don't think so, i will be give input zipcode and distance in miles in google map code and i want output from google map as a list of latitude and longitude from given distance in zipcode wise. example :-  i am enter 95106 zipcode and 30 miles and output will displayed list of latitude and longitude bw that.